# Pyspark - how to create a new line based on the difference of two lines

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe like this:

| Col1 | Col2 | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Antony | Dummy | Type_1 | 30 |
| Antony | Dummy | Type_2 | 20 |

I have to add a new line to get this effect

| Col1 | Col2 | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Antony | Dummy | Type_1 | 30 |
| Antony | Dummy | Type_2 | 20 |
| **Antony** | **Dummy** | **Type_3** | **10**** |

**  the difference of the two lines

Any ideas how to manage it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`lag`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lag) window function to capture previous value(s) then do the calculation